# cypress.io how to remove items for 'n' times, not predictable, while re-rendering list itself

Tags: cypress

I've a unpredictable list of rows to delete

I simply want to click each .fa-times icon

The problem is that, after each click, the vue.js app re-render the remaining rows.

I also tried to use .each, but in this cas I got an error because element (the parent element, I think) has been detached from DOM; cypress.io suggest to use a guard to prevent this error but I've no idea of what does it mean

How to 
- get a list of icons
- click on first
- survive at app rerender
- click on next 
- survive at app rerender
... etch...

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before showing one possible solution, I'd like to preface with a recommendation that tests should be predictable. You should create a defined number of items every time so that you don't have to do hacks like these.

You can also read more on conditional testing, here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#Definition

That being said, maybe you have a valid use case (some fuzz testing perhaps?), so let's go.

What I'm doing in the following example is `(1)` set up a rendering/removing behavior that does what you describe happens in your app. The actual solution `(2)` is this: find out how many items you need to remove by querying the DOM and checking the `length`, and then enqueue that same number of cypress commands that query the DOM every time so that you get a fresh reference to an element.

**Caveat:** After each remove, I'm waiting for the element (its `remove` button to be precise) to not exist in DOM before continuing. If your app re-renders the rest of the items separately, *after* the target item is removed from DOM, you'll need to assert on something else --- such as that a different item (not the one being removed) is removed (detached) from DOM.

```js
describe('test', () => {
  it('test', () => {

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // (1) Mock rendering/removing logic, just for the purpose of this 
    //     demonstration.
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    cy.window().then( win => {
      let items = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
      win.remove = item => {
        items = items.filter( _item => _item !== item );
        setTimeout(() => {
          render();
        }, 100 )
      };
      function render () {
        win.document.body.innerHTML = items.map( item => {
          return `
            <div class="item">
              ${item}
              <button class="remove" onclick="remove('${item}')">Remove</button>
            </div>
          `;
        }).join('');
      }
      render();
    });

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // (2) The actual solution
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    cy.get('.item').then( $elems => {
      // using Lodash to invoke the callback N times
      Cypress._.times($elems.length, () => {
        cy.get('.item:first').find('.remove').click()
          // ensure we wait for the element to be actually removed from DOM
          //  before continuing
          .should('not.exist');
      });
    });
  });
});
```